# Where are you heading (to)? Why can TO be omitted?

Tags: grammar

My Japanese friend asked me why "to" can be omitted in "Where are you heading?"

He asked me if it's because "where" is an adverb but I don't think that's the reason ...

Can someone please help me explain the reason?

Comment: Surely "**to**" can be omitted. "*where*" is indeed an adverb. Basically, both "**Where are you heading**" and "**Where are you heading to**" are synonyms.

Answer (score 2):

The Japanese often use "**to**"  *ni* to describe direction.

> Tokyo ni *(towards / in the direction of Tokyo)*

Your example question

> Where are you heading?

is a shortended form of

> Where are you **heading *(off)* to**?
>   **To** where are you **heading *(off)***?

A **heading** is a navagational term meaning *in the direction* so the "**to**" can be implied.

If you are driving, you might say

> We are **heading** east on I-95.
>   We are **heading** towards New York City.

The British will use the term

> When are you **heading off**? *(BrE)
>   When are you going / leaving? *(AmE)*

Comment: Thank you for the explanation :) Really appreciate it. That's how I was thinking of explaining it.

Comment: By the way, are you studying Japanese? You can also use へ or へと to indicate direction in Japanese although the usage/meaning does slightly differ.

Answer (score 1):

The preposition is not always needed in English. Consider these examples:

> Where are you going? I'm going to London.
>
> Where did you grow up? I grew up on a farm.  *the verb is "grow up"*
>
> How do you write? I write with a pen.

The preposition is not required, and with "where" questions it is normally not used. (In Japanese a particle would be necessary.)  However, with "what" questions a preposition would often be required.

> What are you writing? I'm writing a book.
>
> What are you writing with? I'm writing with a pen.

One common exception is the "where...from" pattern.

> Where do you come from?

instead of "where do you come".

Comment: Ah, you're right! A particle would be necessary in Japanese. Maybe that's why he was so confused about that. 

And thank you for the input. I'll explain what you said in Japanese :)